# Float to decimal and decimal to float. All conversions in general

Tags: c#, type-conversion

Im studying to learn C#. Im at a complete loss as to why and what are the correct answers here. I have searched much and found nothing. People explain, yet there is no explanation to be found. What are the correct answers and why?

During which of the following conversions might there be a loss of precision?

- a. Converting an int to a float
- b. Converting a float to a long
- c. Converting a long to an int
- d. Converting an int to a long
- e. Converting a float to a decimal
- f. Converting a decimal to a float

Why are both float to decimal and decimal to float a possible loss of precision conversion..?

Comment: But in what way does a long to an int cause loss of precision? It doesnt.

Comment: Whenever you refer to "loss of precision" you are actually referring to potential loss

Comment: Well, consider the long value `12345678900L`. How much is it in `int`?

Comment: -55 something, something.

Comment: The book says that ABEF are the correct answers. Why?

Comment: Maybe the question is asking you to examine a specific number that is within range in ABEF cases thus no loss occurs.

Comment: There is no specific number that I am aware of. Is it because float stores its bits differently than from decimal? Then I can see that both cases must round upwards or downwards, if they have the bits displaced in relation to each other. Could this be the answer? Even though I have no idea what this would mean in reality. Is it way too complicated for the average programmer?

Comment: Quick answer, all of them but `int` to `long`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> During which of the following conversions might there be a loss of precision?
>   a. Converting an int to a float

`int` has 32 bits of precision, used entirely for the non-fractional portion of a number. `float` has 32 bits of precision, but some of those bits are used for the exponent, leaving fewer than 32 bits to represent the mantissa. Thus, there are numbers that can be represented as `int` but which cannot as `float`.

For example:

```
int i = int.MaxValue; // = 2147483647
float f = (float)i;   // = 2147484000 --> lost last three digits!
```

> b. Converting a float to a long

I hope it's easy for you to see how conversions from floating point to integer types can lose precision.

> c. Converting a long to an int

That your book did not mention this as a problem indicates that it's distinguishing loss of precision from loss of accuracy (just FYI).

In C#, `long` is 64 bits while `int` is only 32 bits. Any number larger than `int.MaxValue` (i.e. `2147483647`) cannot be represented by `int`, but many such numbers can be represented by `long`. Converting any such number from `long` to `int` will result in a loss of accuracy, i.e. the resulting number is not even close to the correct number.

Arguably it has *also* lost precision, but I guess your book is focusing on situations where *only* precision is lost?

> d. Converting an int to a long

I assume you understand why this doesn't lose precision (or accuracy).

> e. Converting a float to a decimal
>   f. Converting a decimal to a float
>   Why are both float to decimal and decimal to float a possible loss of precision conversion..?

`decimal` to `float` is a little easier to explain: the reason we even use `decimal` in the first place is because the normal `float` numeric type simply can't represent certain values that `decimal` can and which are important for common types of calculations (e.g. monetary computations), and for other values `decimal` also can't represent it can at least represent them more closely.

For example:

```
float f = 1f / 3;
decimal d = 1M / 3;
float f2 = (float)d;
```

In the above, the variable `f` will have the value `0.333333343`, while the variable `d` will have the value `0.3333333333333333333333333333`. Neither are exact (since 1/3 is a repeating decimal, it can't be represented by a finite computer), but the `decimal` version is a lot closer to the correct answer.

Similarly, converting from `decimal` back to `float` results in a loss of precision, as the variable `f2` winds up with the same value that `f` did: `0.333333343`.

But what about conversion from `float` to `decimal`?

Well, while `decimal` has more significant digits of precision than `float` does (about 28 vs 7), the `float` type supports numbers with magnitude as small as `1.401298E-45` (i.e. `float.Epsilon`). But `decimal` can't represent numbers with such small magnitude (it can only represent magnitudes as small as about `1E-28`). Converting `float` numbers with magnitudes smaller than what `decimal` can represent will result in a value of `0`, losing those significant decimal digits.

Put another way: while `float` only has 7 digits of precision and `decimal` has 28, `float` can move those digits much farther to the right of the decimal point than `decimal` can, allowing for smaller-magnitude numbers in `float` than `decimal` can represent.

Thus, it is possible to lose precision going either way (and that's why there aren't implicit conversions in C# between those types…it offers implicit conversions only when there's no loss of information).

See also:
[Explicit Numeric Conversions Table (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yht2cx7b.aspx)
[Single Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Single(v=vs.110).aspx)
[Decimal Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx)
[Difference between Decimal, Float and Double in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-net)

Comment: Beautifully written. I wish you the best and I thank you very much for your explanation. I will be sure to check out those links as well.